# python-crfsuite for Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip, crf, python-crfsuite

I want to install python-crfsuite in Ubuntu. When I install using pip, I'm getting some warning and

> Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for python-crfsuite

When I import crfutils in python, it is saying module not found. What could be the problem or is it is not possible in Linux system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install important tools

```
$ apt-get install swig
```

Download the dependencies.

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/chokkan/liblbfgs/liblbfgs-1.10.tar.gz
```

Decompress. Go to the resulting directory. Type `./configure`. Then `make`. Then `make install`.

Download the actual software source.

```
$ wget https://github.com/downloads/chokkan/crfsuite/crfsuite-0.12.tar.gz
```

Decompress the file. Go to the resulting directory. Type `./configure`. Then `make`. Go to the `swig>python` directory. Type

```
$ ./prepare.sh --swig
$ python setup.py build_ext
$ python setup.py install
```

You may need to manually edit `export_wrapper.cpp`, but the fix is included in `README`

You may need to add `/usr/local/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you get `ImportError: libcrfsuite-0.12.so`.

Comment: there are a few more steps to this. I will edit the post with the full procedure.

Comment: Note that python-crfsuite is not the same as official swig crfsuite wrapper, it is a separate package. Commands above will install a swig-based wrapper.